# Why did Jacob also collect earrings along with the idols?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avodah-zarah, vayishlach, jewelry

In parshat Vayishlach ([35:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0135.htm)), after the people of the town of Shechem are acquired, Jacob tells the group travelling with him to give him all the idols with them. They give him both their idols and earrings.

A) Why the earrings?

B) I'm sure they would've had nose rings as well. Why not those?

Comment: I was thinking about this and was curious whether there was anyone who connects this incidence with the Eigel HaZahav and the jewelry used there...

Comment: possibly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/symbolism-behind-earrings-used-for-the-golden-calf/40797#40797

Answer (score 3):

[Targum Yonasan ben Uziel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=453) says that the earings they gave to Yaakov had a picture of an idol in them.

Answer (score 2):

[R. Dovid Zvi Hoffmann](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/hofman/hof_br35.pdf) says that these earings were in the form of idols and the words אשר בידם would imply that (any kind of) jewelry in their possession was often in form of idols.